# c# - search listview items using textbox

Tags: c#, listview, search, textbox

I am working on a project (simple phone book) for personal use.

Here you can take a look how it looks like:

**IMAGE**: http://s24.postimg.org/3qlicrcdx/Kruzeri.png

I am just about to finish it, but first I have to configure search bar to work properly. I would like it to find the contact I have entered in the textBox7. Ideally, first of all I would have to enter contact's name and then press the search button located right by the textbox. Then, it should select the contact I was searching for.

I have tried to solve this in numerous ways but with no success.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

If needed, I have uploaded the whole code here where you can take a look at it:

**LINK**: http://www.sendspace.com/file/qa8rnq

Answer (score 0):

If you use binding to fill your listbox, then you can just filter your list. For example:

```
element.ItemsSource = contactlist.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("SearchName")).
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where should I put the line exactly and what should I replace "SearchName" with, when you take into account that I want it to search by the text I entered in the textbox?

Comment: This should be put into the buttonClick-Event. The string "SearchName" would be the content of the textBox7 (textBox7.Text).

Comment: Edgar, thank you once again. I have tried the code above but this is not working for me, probably because I haven't done it in the proper way. Please, be more specific. What should I put instead of "element" and instead of "contactlist"? Here is the code I tried - IMAGE: http://s24.postimg.org/luoixea2d/Kruzeri.png

Comment: Element is the listbox with your contacts (listView1). Contactlist is the the IEnumarable wich contains your contacts (people).

Comment: I just looked at your code and you dont use binding so you must do the following: var templist = contactlist.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(textBox7.Text)); listView1.Items.Clear; foreach (var contact in templist){ listView1.Items.Add(contact.Name); }

Answer (score 0):

Have you read on regular expressions (RegEx)? That way you wouldn't need to write the exact name.

Plus, you should start naming your controls properly. Instead of textBox7, name it something like txtSearch. Using the prefix for the control "type".

Button: btnDoStuff
Textbox: txtDoStuff
etc..

Comment: Thank you for your response, anyway, I am quite new to c# so I am still catching things. Could you be more specific?